# Nvidia GPU - OpenCL Profiling and Performance Counters

Tags: profiling, opencl, nvidia, performancecounter

I am using OpenCL on an Nvidia GTX-970 (Linux-Ubuntu).

I want to profile my OpenCL kernels by reading performance counters for metrics like cache miss rates, SIMD Utilization, branch divergence etc. I have looked up online, but could not find anything for this case. AMD has its own APP Profiler from which one can get these stats, but i could not find something similar for an OpenCL kernel running on an Nvidia GPU.

Any ideas? I would like to read performance counter values in OpenCL.

I also asked this question on Nvidia's developer forums and the Khronos forums but didnt get any reply.

Thanks

Comment: http://uob-hpc.github.io/2015/05/27/nvvp-import-opencl/

Comment: Wow that worked! I still have to write a program to visualize the results fron the dumped file though.
Thanks, you may want to add that as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: This looked interesting... I wonder if the related document is available somewere or if someone could create an answer with it.